# What does ^= mean in CSS?

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors

In CSS, what does the `^=` means?

See this code:

```
$(".navbar-dark ul li a[href^='#']").on('click', function(e) { }
```

Comment: ^= means _starts with_

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/  (Since you're using it in the context of a jQuery selector after all)

Comment: this is javascript (jQuery) and not css

Comment: @Lelio Faieta: Normally I'd be the one to quibble over that sort of thing, but in this case it really makes no difference - both versions are exactly the same.

Comment: A more important question.... Whats does `"Tks!"` mean?

Comment: @BoltClock you are right. My point was more related to the provided example :)

Answer (score 2):

it is an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

> **[attr^=value]**
>
> Represents an element with an attribute name of attr and whose first value is prefixed by "value".

Lets see an example:

```css
[class^="red"] {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<div class="redish">text</div>
<div class="red">text</div>
<div class="redding">text</div>
```